# Why does the page show blank white screen?And, how can I remove the error shown in console?

Tags: reactjs, redux, e-commerce, mern

It is a MERN eCommerce Web Application. Why the page is blank(white screen) and What is the error in the console?
I have provided a screenshot(linked as My Web App in the browser) of my browser where you can see the white screen and an error. The error is pointing towards the code that I have written as the code below.

[My Web App in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS3QD.png)

Code in **store.js** file

```
import {combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import {
  newProductReducer,
  newReviewReducer,
  productDetailsReducer,
  productReducer,
  productReviewsReducer,
  productsReducer,
  reviewReducer,
} from "./reducers/productReducer";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  products: productsReducer,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
  newReview: newReviewReducer,
  newProduct: newProductReducer,
  product: productReducer,
  productReviews: productReviewsReducer,
  review: reviewReducer,
});

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = configureStore(
  reducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Because your code posted is not related to page rendering.
And you need to put a screenshot  for console log as well.

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot. Click on"My Web App in browser"